# Keep :hover effect on parent, when mouse is over child

Tags: jquery, html, css, parent

I have a new problem with my menu.

I want to keep the parent hover effect active when mouse is over child.

I know I could maybe use jQuery? but I really wanna keep it in CSS if possible.

And without having to give all elements unique id's...

http://forevertan.dk/_temp/eventfest/3/test3.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a CSS only way, what I highly recommend to you, you would have to change your markup a little bit.
When you check for `:hover` on `a`'s parent (the `li`) `a` will still be on `:hover` when you go down the submenu.
Basically we're doing this:

```
ul#nav li > a {
    /* all the normal state styling here */
}
ul#nav li:hover > a {
    /* hover state styling here */
}
```

We will expand the `a` to the dimensions of the `li`. So the `li` seems to behave like the `a`. The only difference is, that the `li` is the parent of the `a` *and* the submenu `ul`.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ns2Kd/).

HTML stays the same:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#test">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#test/sub">Sub</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#test">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#test/sub">Sub</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS changes:

```
ul#nav > li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
ul#nav li > a {
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;

    display: block;

    background: #000;

    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#nav li:hover > a {
    background: #FFF;

    color: #000;
}
ul#nav > li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
ul#nav > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
ul#nav > li ul li {
    display: block;
}.
```

Comment: Just tryed with what you made..
Cant really get it to work? 
It acts pretty strange?

Can you make a quick working example?

Comment: Got 1 problem though.. cant seem to style the text in the submenu?
The submenu text need to be smaller, and everything i tried just doesnt seem to affect it?
Even tried a class on the li's

Comment: `ul#nav li > a` styles both. Mainmenu and Submenu. You'll have to change the selctor to this: `ul#nav > li > a`.

Comment: +1: came from Google, and got the point from your solution to do what the main doubt was asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Put the :hover selector on the `li` element rather than the anchor

```
#navMain li:hover > a{
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/293mV/

Comment: That's not quite what he's describing. This changes the child when the parent is hovered not the other way around.

Comment: I will just add that this is true but with IE6 `li:hover` will not work.  With IE6 the pseudo selector `:hover` is only valid on an `a` element

Comment: @Diodeus: The request is to _keep_ the parent _effect_ even when the mouse is over the child. By triggering off the li instead of the a, the top level a is shown in hover state when the mouse is over the top level link _and_ when it is over any child element. This is exactly what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot effect parent items with CSS; you need to use JavaScript. If you don't like IDs you can use jQuery's relative selectors `.parent()`, `.next()` etc.